# Display Object in front of player without considering its rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can show another object in front of my player using this simple line of code

```
newPosition =player.transform.position+player.transform.forward * distance
```

but how can i restrict it to always show in the same position(but in front of player) no matter what is the **rotation of my player**?

Answer (score 0):

When you rotate gameobject `transform.forward` always changes.Because of you are using local values. But you need the use word values for this.

```
newPosition =player.transform.position+Vector3.forward * distance
```

Comment: thanks but if i use this then i will unable to show my object in front of the player

Comment: I want to that if a player look at forward then object show in front of him but not changed the position

Comment: It sounds like you need to rotate the object to match the player's rotation (probably just around the vertical axis) so the same side of the object is always facing the player